# Water heater pump - Usage in Room UK Travel

Tags: uk, power

We came to UK from India and in our room there are two switch. One "water heater pump" and one "water heater" as shown
[image]

I understand that water heater if switched on then only we get hot water - obvious
1)What is the control of Water heater pump?
2)There is a pin timer beside this. Should i always keep the water heater on and pump on when the pin timer is time controlled - that is at middle position of the pin timer?

Comment: Have you tried asking the landlord or accommodation provider such as hotel owner or manager?

Comment: This looks like a custom installation rather than anything typical.  So as per Michael, asking someone local is probably our best bet

Comment: @PeterM TBH it looks like a lash-up! I'm in the UK, do quite a bit of my own electrics and plumbing, and haven't seen this setup before.  I could make some guesses but that's all they'd be.  I'm confident to experiment but the OP should the host/hotel manager or similar

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the image is no longer available so it's hard to answer the original question